# Solving a system of Quadratic Equations

Tags: python, equation, sqrt

I am doing a cryptography program in Python.

It consists in reading a random phrase, like `HELLO`. Then it assigns it's respective ASCII values like:

```
H = 72, E = 79.
```

Then, using Pythagoras' Theorem, it creates two numbers `C1` and `C2`, like this:

```
C1 = sqrt(A^2 + (A+B)^2);
C2 = sqrt(B^2 + (A+B)^2)
```

where, in this case `A = H` and `B = E`. That would be the encryption part, but I am having problems solving the system, which will act as the decryptor.

How can I solve this system using python?

```
C1 = sqrt(A^2 + (A+B)^2); 
C2 = sqrt(B^2 + (A+B)^2);
```

Of course only `C1` and `C2` are known.

Do I need a new module? Which one?

Comment: You don't need Python to solve this system. You need piece of paper and a bit of school math skills to transform it into formulas for A and B. After that you can write this formulas in Python -> PROFIT!

Comment: Actually I have been trying to solve A and B, but I couldn't, so I think about a numeric solution to it.

Comment: Will potential attackers have access to the C1/2 values? Because, if you're really only talking about using two characters as the key, that means (1) you can brute force the solution without any complex math, it only takes 64,000-odd attempts; and (2) so can an attacker.

Comment: Well, It's a way to think about it, i want to take all the characters in the phrase. Also is a way to do it, if i need something a little bit more sophisticated, I will improve it.

Comment: Or any of you have an idea of another way to do the encrytation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only talking about using the two characters for encryption, that's not a good idea.

That only gives 65,536 possible variants (two ASCII characters was mentioned but I'll assume a full 8-bit octet, so 256 multiplied by 256), it's easy enough to brute-force this. First, we *know* that every value of `A` and `B` generates a unique pair `C1/C2`, as per the following program which generates no duplicates:

```
lookup = {}
for a in range(256):
    for b in range(256):
        c1s = a*a + (a+b)*(a+b)
        c2s = b*b + (a+b)*(a+b)
        lkey = "%d:%d"%(c1s,c2s)
        lookup[lkey] = 1
print(len(lookup))                 # gives 65536 (256 squared)
```

Also, since both `A` and `B` are integers, so too will be `C12` and `C22`.

So the first step is to work out the squares of the values you're given (since `sqrt` is a potentially expensive operation), taking into account the possibility of floating point inaccuracies:

```
c1s = int(c1 * c1 + 0.1)
c2s = int(c2 * c2 + 0.1)
```

Then, simply brute-force the solution:

```
for a in range(256):
    for b in range(256):
        if c1s != a*a + (a+b)*(a+b):
            continue
        if c2s == b*b + (a+b)*(a+b):
            print(a,b)
            sys.exit(0)
print("No solution")
```

On my machine, searching for the slowest solution (both `a` and `b` set to 255), it takes just a smidgeon over six *hundredths* of a second.

But you should keep in mind that, if an attacker has the `C1/C2` values, they too can get the results that fast. And, even if they *don't* have it, the fact that there are only 64K possibilities means that they can try every possible value in a little over one and a quarter hours. So I wouldn't be using this method to store anything that's valuable for very long :-)

Comment: But nobody will know how to calculate C1 or C2. That's just between you people and me. Btw, I manage to solve the equations for B, it's just replace it in one of the equations. 

Don't worry about what I will encrypt. :D Thanks!

Comment: Also, the encryptation result will be something like:

23.34,23.67,12.34,45,66... And so on, those are the C1 and C2 of each pair of characters.

The only way to decrypt it is knowing what is the patron used to obtain C1 and C2 in first place.

Comment: @Carlos, based on your comments, there seems to be a bit of information missing. As stated, it's relatively easy to recover A and B from C1 and C2, even in pairs, so I have to assume you're using those values somehow to encrypt the plaintext (rather than having HELLO as the plaintext). How is that being done?

Comment: I have a question. Solving the equation, there are too many possible values for A and B, is there anything i can do, by codding to choose the correct values of A and B?

Comment: @Carlos, in a conversation. it's usually the done thing to address any questions raised previously before asking something totally different :-) I can't really offer more help until I fully understand *how* the encryption is being done, something I'm not getting from your question. I'd suggest clarifying it.